# Application stops unexpectedly with the following error log

Tags: android-emulator

Am new to android..am working on an app that retreives GPS coordinates from a force.com database but is currently experiencing an error.Some please help.I have included all necessities in the manifest file

```
11-23 14:57:14.014: D/AndroidRuntime(309): Shutting down VM
11-23 14:57:14.014: W/dalvikvm(309): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {net.myproject.okello/net.myproject.okello.DisplayPlotsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at net.myproject.okello.DisplayPlotsActivity.onResume(DisplayPlotsActivity.java:137)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
11-23 14:57:14.064: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 12 more
11-23 14:57:17.314: I/Process(309): Sending signal. PID: 309 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Hi, when posting code or logs, you can use the code tags to make the post auto-format itself, so that's more readable.